# linking image with img tag inside index.html not woking - Currently using webpack url-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack

i am using webpack "url-loader", which helps me create "img tag element" in JS and append on certain node. And currently this loader looks on the size to decide whether to make it inline or put it as a file inside "build".

```
{
            test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/, 
            loader: "url-loader?limit=5000"
        }  
// Portion of my webpack config file.
```

How ever i am looking a much simpler task of referring image with "img" tag inside index.html. eg:

```
<img src="logo.png" alt=""/>
```

Since "logo.png" image is not copied to build folder, i am not able to refer it inside index.html with simple img tag.

[image]

Comment: Could you manage `index.html` through webpack (i.e. through [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin)) or does it have to be separate from webpack?

Comment: i do not require it to be managed by webpack as there is no need for me at this point. 

All i want is to somehow get the images under "images" folder inside "source" to be included in "build" folder without creating "element" via JS. And refer that img file with some thing like this <img src="img_file_name.png" /> inside index file. 

In my gulp build i used to copy file from "source" to "build" but am not sure how to do it in webpack. I would appreciate if i can use both simple referene by <img> tag and using "url-loaders" feature" by file size.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you don't want to stick to file-loader? url-loader will output data urls and if the html isn't under control, there's no way it could work. If you can inject the image tag through JavaScript, then there's no problem. So you may have to relax your problem definition somehow.

Comment: I do not want to inject via js. So can you suggest how to do it via file loader and also how it will work if it is done by taking html under control.

Comment: I have the basic setup at http://survivejs.com/webpack/loading-assets/loading-images/ . file-loader will generate actual files. If you are using hashing, then you need to use webpack stats to figure out the resulting names. But if you skip hashing, you can rely on a filename like in your example.